# Function returns char *

Tags: c++, char

Is it correct to write a function that returns char *?

Something like this:

```
char * func()
{  
 char *c = new char[3];
 strcpy(c, "hi");
 c[2] = '\0';
 return c;
}

int main()
{
 char *c;
 c = func();
 //code using c
 delete [] c;
 return 1;
}
```

It works, but is it correct?

Comment: @Alecs you haven't used `strlen` function properly

Comment: will the data in memory that was allocated in local function remains untouched when we will out of local function?

Comment: No, because the code won't compile...

Comment: @Pradeep sorry, that was a typo. I mean strcpy

Comment: Editing the compilation issue.

Comment: As an aside, the `c[2] = '\0';` is unnecessary, `strcpy` already does that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is correct (assuming you meant `strcpy` and not `strlen`), but it must be very clear from the documentation of the function that it's the caller's responsibility to free the returned pointer, and what method does it have to use to free it (`new` => `delete`, `new []` => `delete[]`, `malloc` => `free`, etc). That is the "C way" of doing it.

This relies on users of your function (including you after several months you wrote it) to read the documentation to get things right, so it's quite error prone; also, in C++ there are several more complications that are not present in C (namely: exceptions) that make using raw pointers in these contexts not such a good idea.

That's the reason why you normally should return classes that encapsulate resources (e.g. `std::string` in this case, and in general containers that manage the memory automatically) or ownership-transferring smart pointers, that also have the advantage of being exception-safe (which your code is not).

This sounds extremely complicated, but in fact it's not:

```
#include <string>

std::string func()
{  
   return "hi"; // actually, to be more explicit it should be return std::string("hi")
}

int main()
{
    std::string c;
    c=func();
    return 1;
}
```

That's it, no need to worry about allocations/deallocations and exceptions, all this is automatically handled by the `std::string` class, so you can manage strings almost as they were builtin types.

Comment: And free it with `delete[]`, _not_ `free`.

Comment: I think if he's asking a question like this, he's not really worried about documentation and encapsulations and smart pointers and exceptions and things like that.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I expanded the answer.

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly why Matteo Italia mentioned these things.

Comment: @quasiverse: using smart pointers and STL containers makes programming in C++ easier even for beginners; also, I think that newbies must be taught RAII from the beginning, it's fundamental for writing correct C++ code.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that works. The memory is allocated on the heap and is deallocated correctly. There is no need to manually add a null-terminator since `strcpy` does so.

But it's not really C++. In C++ you would use `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

> It works, but is it correct?

Your code is **correct**.

However, it depends on the context, if it's a good programming practice or not. For this minimal program you posted, I will prefer not to use `new[]` and `delete[]`. But would rather rely on `std::string`.

[Demo](http://www.ideone.com/LMoMM).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is technically correct. However, I think most SO-ers here have reservations on whether it's considered "good" code or not.

For starters:

- Pick meaningful variable/function names. `c` and `func` are not very descriptive and make it difficult for others to understand what you're trying to do
- Generally you should have a corresponding function which cleans up any resources that your function has allocated.
- Prefer `strncpy()` over `strcpy()` to prevent unexpected buffer overflows (or look into the String class)

Comment: 1) I know, I decided that for such small example the short names are better 2) in this case how can I write function that will clean up? 3) in my real program I use strncpy, that's why I automatically added the '\0' char manually

Comment: Sadly, `strncpy` is not the counted version of `strcpy`, but it's a function thought for fixed-size buffers; it adds useless NUL padding when the string to be copied is shorter than the buffer but doesn't NUL terminate it when it's longer. I think that the best standard counted alternative to `strcpy` is `*target=0; strncat(target, source, size);`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
char * func()
{  
 char * c = new char[3];
 strcpy(c,"hi");
 return c;
}

int main()
{
 char *c;
 c = func();
 //code using c
 delete [] c;
 return 0;
}
```